# Angular refactoring controller into service

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-services

I'd like to create a service that I can use in several controllers. The service is essentially just returning JSON data that I'm using throughout several pages. I'd like to have two controllers, one for an "event page" and one for an "event details" page. I'd like the query to return the entire data object on the "event" page and filter to one event for the "event details" page. My logic is that I could pass in the $routeParams as a parameter for the query function on the "event details page".

My controller looks like this: I currently just have the one controller for two routes, I'd like one service and two controllers. One controller returning the entire data set and one just returning the filtered data set.

```
app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$routeParams' function ($scope, $resource, $routeParams) { 
  var Hc = $resource('/api/hc');

 Hc.query(function(results){
    $scope.events = results;

});

  $scope.events = []

}]);
```

My $routeProvider when statements are here:

```
.when('/events', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
            controller: 'eventController'
    })

    .when('/events/:eventName', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/eventdetail.html',
        controller: 'eventController'
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
app.factory("HC", ["$resource", function($resource) {
    return {
        API: $resource('/api/hc')
    }
}]);
```

And then in your controller:

```
app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', 'HC', '$routeParams' function ($scope, HC $routeParams) {

    HC.API.query(function(results) {
        $scope.events = results
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was unsure about what to do with $scope and $resource. How would I go about filtering by $routeParams?